# Styling child component to show to the left side of the parent component

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, parent-child

**I need to create the CSS style to launch a component of the left side of the parent component.**

I have the following structure:

```
----panelComponent(parent)
-------inputComponent(parent)
----------otherComponent(child)
```

I'm trying to trigger that when an user trigger the `otherComponent` which is child of `inputComponent`, its appears in the left side of the `inputComponent` because the components are on the left of the screen and the other Component is not having been showing in the correct way.
This is the problem:
[image: The panel with the grid is looking cut]

I want to show the panel with the grid on the left side of the `inputComponent`(parent) just as in the next image:
[image: This is the correct behavior]

The code that I'm using to call the otherComponent in the inputComponent is something similar to this:

```
<div #parentReference></div>
<input>
  <span class="ra-ui-input-suffix">
    <ra-ui-icon-button
      (click)="openOtherComponent()"
    >
    </ra-ui-icon-button>
  </span>
</input>
<ng-template #otherComponent>
  <other-component></other-component>
</ng-template>
```

The `otherComponent` is designed to be launched under the component who calls it. I need to create an style to launch the `otherComponent` at the left side of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you feel about jQuery;
but you could add an event listener to the #Othercomponent and when fired, use:

```
let otherComponent = $("#other-component);
otherComponent && otherComponent.addEventListener('onclick', () => {
  $("#other-component").parent().addClass('classNameWithApplicableStyle');
})
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, but I can't use jQuery in this project. I need to use CSS to stylize the view of my components.

Comment: I don't know Angular; but React allows you to pass props down from the parent component based on state. i.e. panelComponent has a state which tells the inputComponent how to render. the other-component has an eventHandler that changes the state of the PanelComponent, which in turn modifies the inputComponent's style.

Answer (score 0):

It might bring more problems than it solves, but how about manipulating the positioning of the component? Like `left: -100px`; especially, if the width of the parent component is fixed and you can hardcode it. Here: I'll move this button outside of its parent:
[image]